# Terminal issues error message that no Django module "models" exists, but it is in the directory

Tags: django-models

I'm a motivated beginner working my way through Python Crash Course. I created a project and an app using Django. I'm unable to get the python manage.py run server command to work.  This is the header of the long error message:
"Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Django-main-thread".
The middle includes several lines of "".
At the end, it says "from models import Activity"
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models''

There IS a module named models in the directory. This is my second exercise using Django, and the program worked earlier. I've searched the net and read everything remotely similar, but have been unable to find a solution.  How can I make the program recognize a module that is there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that the version of pip in the virtual environment was the python 2.7 version instead of the 3.9 version I used to create the project. It had to be upgraded using:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

I also used python3 for the manage.py runserver command instead of just python.

Comment: If you have Python 2 and Python 3 on your system, as is the case on macOS and many Linux distros, you need to make sure and use the Python 3 installation to create the virtual environment. If you did that, check to make sure you're in an active virtual environment. In an active virtual environment, you can run `python -V` to see which version was used to make the venv. If the venv was built incorrectly, you can always just delete the venv directory and rebuild it. It shouldn't affect your project code at all. You'll need to reinstall django to the venv though

Comment: Thank you for the  python -V technique! It does seem that despite my having 3.9, it often defaults back to the 2.7 without my realizing it.  Now I have a way to double check, and anything the reduces debugging time frustration is greatly appreciated.